# Unable to use Box API after installing nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-core, box

I started  using `Box.V2` in my asp dotnet core app in VSCode, but I was getting all kinds of annoying errors.

After finding that there is a specific nuget package for dotnet core, I uninstalled my existing box packages and installed `Box.V2.Core` - it appears to have installed successfully as I can see it on my installed packages list.

However, When I try `using Box.V2.Core` I get a

> The type or namespace 'Box' could not be found

What am I supposed to do with this? Does the package actually not exist?

My csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.6.362"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices" Version="4.3.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="2.0.0-preview1-25914-04"/>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore" Version="1.5.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.2.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Box.V2.Core" Version="3.4.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something strange is definitely going on with that package. I suggest first installing one release down: `<PackageReference Include="Box.V2.Core" Version="3.3.0" />` and then updating it back to 3.4.1.